# How to create tests for QGIS' processing models

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

**Short version:** Is there a way to create automated tests inside my own processing models?

**Extended version:**

I am just starting with QGIS' processing to create some complex model which makes quite a lot of changes and I would like to know if there is a way to test my own model while launching it, so if the tests fail, I can get a notification and I will know that something went wrong before I realize too late and I have to lose any changes I made after executing the model with unexpected results.

**Example**:

I am doing several joins and spatial joins. I learnt the hard way that after triggering several times my model, every time I was joining layers, new fields were added with a `_1` appended to them in order not to overwrite the previously created fields by mistake when I repeated the model.
It would be great to have some test that either checked all the layer's fields or counted its number and, if they weren't as expected, triggered an alarm/dialog box or created a log file.

For the little I know, I assume the way to achieve this is by creating a Python script and add it to my model as one step more, but I don't have any clue on how should that script be in order to interact with the model.